# JavaFX: How to setText of ComboBoxes and ToggleButtons in loop?

Tags: json, loops, javafx, combobox, togglebutton

I have a JavaFX application with a lot of ToggleButtons, ComboBoxes and TextFields organised in lists by their types. I have also a JSON file with list of my Member's class objects.

Ofcourse I have a @FXML adnotations buttons for buttons, etc.

When my app launch I want to set for everyone ToggleButton a specific Text what I have prepared in JSON file for specific Member. I planned to do this by using initialize() method to call my method fillToggleButtons():

```
List<Member> membersFromJSON = new ArrayList<>();
List<ToggleButton> sendToTeamMembers = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

```
private void fillToggleButtons() {

    Reader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader(JSONFilePaths.membersJSONFilePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type memberList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Member>>() {}.getType();
    List<Member> members = gson.fromJson(reader, memberList);

    for (int i = 0; i < sendToTeamMembers.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < members.size(); k++) {
                sendToTeamMembers.get(i).setText(members.get(k).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I do this, my loops don't work. I have the same Text for everyone ToggleButton, but in JSON file I have them different. Do I need an ObservableList here instead of standard java List?

The same question for ComboBoxes (I know I should use index, also I have it in the same JSON file as Member's ID/index).

What should I do for set Text in loop for JavaFX objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop logic is wrong - you're setting each `ToggleButton`'s text multiple times (first to `members.get(0).getName()`, then to `members.get(1).getName()`, etc).
In the end, each `ToggleButton` will have its name set to the name of the last member from the list.

You only need one `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sendToTeamMembers.size(); i++) {
    sendToTeamMembers.get(i).setText(members.get(i).getName());
}
```

Be sure to check if `members` list contains at least `sendToTeamMembers.size()` elements before you call the code above - and if it doesn't, there's probably some error with loading/parsing your `JSON` file that you'll need to fix first.